# Register QRectF with Boost Geometry

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-geometry

I want to register [`QRectF`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html) as a [`model::box`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_box.html) with Boost.Geometry. The documentation for [`BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX`](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/register/boost_geometry_register_box.html) states that I should provide two parameters: 'minimum corner (should be public member or method)' and 'maximum corner (should be public member or method)' as the last two parameters to the macro. However when trying this with `QRectF` I get the following error:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(QRectF, QPointF, topLeft, bottomRight);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It appears that these parameters have to be public members. There doesn't seem to be a macro where I can specify getter and setter methods equivalent to [`BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/register/boost_geometry_register_point_2d_get_set.html).

I am invoking the macro as follows:

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <QRectF>
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(QPointF, qreal, cs::cartesian, x, y, setX, setY);
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(QRectF, QPointF, topLeft, bottomRight);
```

Is there a way around this in boost as is? I can work around this by copying data across into a `model::box` instantiation but I would rather have something like `BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX_GET_SET` available to use so that I can avoid copying and use `QRectF` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Somebody posted a correct answer to this yesterday but deleted it before I could accept it. Anyway the solution was to use:

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(QRectF, QPointF, topLeft(), bottomRight());
```

As if you look at the implementation of `BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(Box, Point, MinCorner, MaxCorner)` it uses the parameters like so:

```
typedef typename coordinate_type<Point>::type ct; \
static inline ct get(Box const& b) \
{ return geometry::get<D>(b. MinCorner);  } \
```

Which when substituted becomes:

```
typedef typename coordinate_type<QPointF>::type ct; \
static inline ct get(QRectF const& b) \
{ return geometry::get<D>(b. topLeft());  } \
```

Comment: There is no deleted answer on this question though.